# Easy way to gather file sizes of unc paths?

Tags: path, unc

Is there a program or a script I can run against a csv containing thousands of UNC paths? Something not very intrusive - simply looking to gather file sizes of each.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to mash together a bunch of components of PowerShell fairly simply to do what you want.

However, due to the nature of gathering sizes of a folder containing many files, it will be relatively intrusive - i.e. IO-intensive and will take a while to run. This is a consequence of how filesystems work (the size of a folder is not stored anywhere, it must be computed by traversing the folder recording the sizes of files as it goes.

There's [an article in the TechNet Library about determining the size of a (single) folder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730945.aspx) which would probably be useful to you.

PowerShell also has cmdlets called [Import-Csv](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx) and [Export-Csv](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176825.aspx) which will be useful for dealing with CSV data.

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to Server Fault! If this answer is to your satisfaction, please mark my response as "accepted" by clicking the green check besides the answer.